# Hello. I'm trying to get file indexing program with C

Tags: c, file, indexing, messagebox

I am making a file indexing program.
I found a source from google.

Original one is like this...

==================

```
void main()
{
    _finddata_t fd;
    long handle;
    int result = 1;
    handle = _findfirst(".\\*.*", &fd); 

    if (handle == -1)
    {
        printf("There were no files.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (result != -1)
    {
        printf("File: %s\n", fd.name);
        result = _findnext(handle, &fd);
    }

    _findclose(handle);

    return;
}
```

===================

It works. But I wanted to get number of found files and display it to a MessageBox.

So I tried with this code...

=============

```
void main()
{
    _finddata_t fd;
    long handle;
    int result = 1;
    handle = _findfirst(".\\*.*", &fd);  //현재 폴더 내 모든 파일을 찾는다.
    int i = 0;
    LPWSTR str = NULL;

    if (handle == -1)
    {
        printf("There were no files.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (result != -1)
    {
        printf("File: %s\n", fd.name);
        result = _findnext(handle, &fd);
        i++;
    }

    _findclose(handle);

    wsprintf(str, L"%d Files were found", i);
    MessageBox(NULL, str, L"Result", MB_OK);
    return;
}
```

============

It doesn't work. It has this error...

```
Exception thrown at 0x76C73566 (user32.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

How can I fix it and make my purpose?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You declared and init `str` at NULL.

```
LPWSTR str = NULL;
```

Then you can't do `wsprintf(str, L"%d Files were found", i);`

Comment: Oops... I don't know how to do then.

Answer (score 0):

`LPWSTR str = NULL;`
and afterwards
`wsprintf(str, L"%d Files were found", i);`

What do you expect to happen? You need to allocate some space.

Comment: How can I allocate some space for str? Please help me :(

Comment: Well, Microsoft api is not exactly my strong point, but you can use `TCHAR str[150];` (on stack) or dynamically with new. Anyway LPWSTR is a typedef to TCHAR *

Comment: Oh, Succed with TCHAR str[150] without new. Thank you so much!^^